# Question has too many answers? Upwards of 60 answers and keeps getting more

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, close-reasons

I found a question that has gotten upwards of 60+ answers and keeps getting more: [Test method is inconclusive: Test wasn't run. Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311108/test-method-is-inconclusive-test-wasnt-run-error)

Is there a procedure to maybe close this one or something? It would be nice if it maybe linked to a new question about how to find the real error (clicking the "output" button in the resharper window in this case.) Then the real errors could be found and searched for as separate questions. As it currently stands, this question is approaching forum-style, which I never want to go back to!

Anyway, is this grounds for closing the question? Should I create a question on how to find the real errors for searching or something? Thanks.

Comment: *Something* definitely needs to be done to that question: just on the first page, I see four pairs of duplicate answers.

Comment: If an answer is accepted, then the net number of answers should be around 20 at max. Most of the times, answers are duplicates or too similar.

Comment: It should be protected. That was done 9 minutes ago at the time of writing.

Comment: Despite the duplicate answers, there are still a lot of unique answers.  It always amazes me when five different people suggest totally different solutions to a problem, and *still none of them work for me*.

Comment: related: **[When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168)** "feature like this would make it _technically harder_ for me to post an answer. Imagine I am willing to add 20th answer to some question, that would mean I have to pass through checking 19 prior answers before posting my own..."

Comment: Regardless of the protection status: Wouldn't one way to clean this up be to summarize the various reasons in one canonical (probably wiki) answer that mentions all these points? Preferably written by someone who Knows His Stuff® and could sort them based on the ratio between "likelyhood of cause" and "effort to fix" (e.g. the first one could be a "Clean and recompile. If that doesn't work..."). The redundant answers could then be deleted (maybe even the ones that *become* redundant due to this canonical answer). I mean, someonoe *searching* for help doesn't want to read 100 answers anyhow...

Comment: Unfortunate that its protection message doesn't actually mention why it's protected, and would have only stopped three of the answers: "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users."

Comment: If a question can have more than 7 unique answers, shouldn't it be Too Broad? There might be a rare exception to this, but as @Marco13 suggested, it could be rolled up into a wiki answer.

Comment: Looks like it is a 6 year old question that is discussing a problem that can be caused by many different things and people are providing answers for versions of software that didn't exist when the question was asked.

Comment: What a honeypot for bad answers. Most of these answers are not only duplicates but also solutions to a problem that was too vague to reliably answer - so many people have answered "for me it was this <insert typo or basic goof/no repro error like forgetting a reference or calling static instead of public>" which should just be deleted with extreme prejudice. The question is clearly too broad/lacking enough detail in the MCVE to reliably answer (the 60+ answers are evidence of that), so I've voted to close the question.

Comment: In this particular case, there is a build going on behind the scenes and the errors are hidden. There is a way to find the real error, but it could be any of a thousand build errors! Maybe the cleaned up main answer could have the "How to find error details" bit first, then the top detailed answers from there...? It's kinda a hard mess to clean up, since all the "What worked for me.." things are not tied to any real or specific error message.

Comment: Maybe some people didn't even noticed there was a second page, we're not used to that after all on SO. Aniway maybe this question could a global answer to the problem explaining properly what are all the condition to properly execute unit test and what are the possible failures. Also since it's from 2013/2014, maybe some answers aren't up-to-date anymore.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385063/how-to-handle-duplicate-answer-cleanup-on-popular-questions

Comment: @TylerH MCVE? You mean min-reprex?

Comment: Could it be that the bug is back in a new version of the software, and googling for the magic word "inconclusive" sent them all here? :)

Comment: Why not *lock* the question?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Why lock it? Locks are for exceptional cases, either put in place to resolve disputes/rollback wars or to preserve valuable historical content that's no longer on-topic. Locking also prevents the community from curating the question and answers. In this case there's not really a content dispute, and there's not any content worth preserving. There are, however, still a close-worthy question and a bunch of duplicate answers that can be cleaned up/downvoted.

Answer (score 26):

I propose to **just delete the redundant answers**.

I did have that exact problem and ended up on that question. I read every answer hoping that one would be helpful. It didn't bother me that there are many answers - that just means there are a lot of ways to create this problem. That doesn't make the question a bad question - it just makes the problem an annoying problem to have.

None of the answers helped me, so I kept searching and eventually found the solution myself and added it as a new answer.

Was it a bad thing to add a new answer to a question that already had several dozens?

Since nobody added this answer before me, I guess my solution is an unlikely cause to the problem in the question. But I think the answer still adds value. Another poor developer might go through all the answers and find that he had the same problem as me.

I don't think there is anything wrong with that process - that's how SO works. If an answer helps you, you upvote and if you find a different solution to the same problem, you can add it as an answer. People will vote and the best/most useful answer will be at the top.

**The annoying part of the process is the duplicate answers.** It's frustrating to read 'I cleaned and rebuilt the solution and then it worked' 4-5 times. It's not helpful.

So I would just delete the redundant answers.

Having **one wiki answer** is also an acceptable solution. It would be nice to have a clear list of things to try. The problem with that is that you can't vote on individual answers anymore, so they are not sorted by helpfulness. I'd prefer to try the answer that has helped most people first because it's the most likely to solve my problem.

Comment: I think the question is a little bit bad, but only because there is a way to narrow down a solution. If you open the "Unit Test Sessions" window in Visual Studio, then click the terribly placed, label-changing button in the top right, you will then see an output log. You will usually see a message that is still cryptic, but could split up the solutions into smaller groups that could be questions of their own.

Comment: (I guess I don't know if that button is there on all versions of Resharper, but I know it is in the latest few.)

Comment: "...just delete the redundant answers." But in which order. Which of each set of redundant answers should stay? The oldest, the highest upvoted, the longest, the best (subjective).... Sounds like a difficult decision to make.

Comment: @Trilarion the oldest, of course. The newer is just a plagiarism of the older (it maybe be longer and more upvoted because of it but it doesn't matter). See similar discussions on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385063/how-to-handle-duplicate-answer-cleanup-on-popular-questions