# What, if anything, should be done about massive question duplicates?

Tags: discussion

The questions below seems to have been asked many many times. There is no authoritative answer AFIACT and so, while I know the answer enough to recognize it (I think), it's frustrating to try to find it as a reference as it's buried somewhere in all these different Q&As

What, if anything, should be done? Some even have the wrong answer with many votes as the top answer.

I seem to remember Stack Overflow was supposed to be a place to find definitive answers with the votes helping to surface them, but it seems to be failing in this case. I'm sure this isn't the only example of this kind of issue.

Is there something concrete I should do? Should I pick one at random and mark all the rest as duplicates? Should I pick one that has a definitive answer and mark all the rest as dupes? Should I leave a definitive answer on one at random and mark all the rest as duplicates? Should I post the same definitive answer on all of them and cross my fingers one will bubble to the top so people can actually find the correct answer? Should I just let it go?

- *[How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)*
- *[Real mouse position in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas)*
- *[Getting relative mouse position on canvas after scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852075/getting-relative-mouse-position-on-canvas-after-scaling)*
- *[Getting mouse location in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114465/getting-mouse-location-in-canvas)*
- *[Make mouse coordinates relative to <canvas> coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822775/make-mouse-coordinates-relative-to-canvas-coordinates)*
- *[Getting correct mouse position on Canvas when canvas size is relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791286/getting-correct-mouse-position-on-canvas-when-canvas-size-is-relative)*
- *[How do we get the mouse canvas relative x,y coordinates from an onClick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112183/how-do-we-get-the-mouse-canvas-relative-x-y-coordinates-from-an-onclick-event)*
- *[Getting the exact mouse position on canvas inside divisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162385/getting-the-exact-mouse-position-on-canvas-inside-divisons)*
- *[Get the mouse coordinates when clicking on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172115/get-the-mouse-coordinates-when-clicking-on-canvas)*
- *[canvas get points on mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343358/canvas-get-points-on-mouse-events)*
- *[HTML5 Canvas Mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403214/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates)*

Let me guess ... this meta question is also a duplicate :P

Comment: There's always the obvious: find the one with the best answer, and mark the rest as a duplicate of that one. You've got a JavaScript gold badge, so you can do this yourself.

Comment: This happens a lot in Ruby, too. One of the reasons is the abysmal quality of search. There are tons of questions about `&:` in Ruby, for example, but a search doesn't show them. So, even if an asker makes a genuine attempt at finding a duplicate, they aren't able to. And the duplicate question logic in the ask question form also doesn't show them. As an experiment, I even copy&pasted an entire question's markdown source code into the question box once, and that question wasn't suggested as a duplicate!

Comment: Beware though, I don't have time right now to check them all, but my first random click pointed to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791286/getting-correct-mouse-position-on-canvas-when-canvas-size-is-relative), which is not a duplicate of the one you set it to: That question was caused by an issue in OP's code who was not setting the canvas size. Their code was fine and hence they were not asking "How to do X?", but "Why my mean of doing X doesn't work?".

Comment: I guess there is a debate whether or not it's a dupe. To me it seems like a dupe as the answer is "use the correct code for getting a relative position from this dupe Q&A". I see hundreds of questions marked as dupe in that form. User posts bad code, asks "how do I do this correctly" and is marked as dupe linking to correct way to do it. If that's not how dupes are supposed to work then I guess I need some guidelines. Marking as a dupe with a comment something like "Marking as a dupe. The solution is to use the correct way to get relative mouse coords, answer in dupe"?

Comment: No read again the Q/A I linked to. Their problem was that they didn't set the canvas size other than by CSS.

Comment: I see your point. Reopened. But I guess I need to change the title of the question to something less misleading to others. Currently it's "Getting correct mouse position on Canvas when canvas size is relative?"

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Google understands `ruby "&:"` just fine. SO's own search was never considered a serious feature.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: How do you express "my deleted answers containing `&:` tagged with [tag:ruby] but not [tag:ruby-on-rails] and 10 votes" in Google? In [main] search, [that is trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+-%5Bruby-on-rails%5D+%22%26%3A%22+is%3Aanswer+deleted%3Ayes+votes%3A10+user%3Ame), except the quality of the results is crap. For me, that returns 4 results, none of which have anything to do with `&:`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's because it's acting like "&:" means "and".

Answer (score 30):

*For existing duplicate candidates*:

- (vote to) close the questions with the best duplicate target (best question/best answers, *not necessarily the older question*)
- vote to delete the ones that aren't worth keeping as signposts for future users. Depending on the question score, only 3 10k+ votes are needed to delete a closed question after 2 days. Get help from friends
- in some rare cases, you could custom flag for question merging. Moderators can do that, but they generally don't like it, as the questions must be exactly the same (or the answers wouldn't match the merged question). Another difficulty is that merging is one of the rare things that cannot be undone by moderators.
- when the questions are popular and have lots of answers, it doesn't hurt to identify & flag duplicate/copied answers on the same post (see: [How to handle duplicate answer cleanup on popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385063/how-to-handle-duplicate-answer-cleanup-on-popular-questions))
- (that's obvious but) downvote the bad answers (and vote to delete if you have 20k+ rep and answer score is < 0)

*For questions asked again and again*: only one thing to do: (vote to) close as fast as possible.

If you have the gold badge of a question tag, your duplicate close votes are binding: use that power.

Comment: Okay, I will try to find the best answer/question and mark the rest as dupes if they really are dupes (and the rest you mentioned)

Comment: If there are ones with unique and good answers spread over several questions, mod-flagging for question merger is also an option

Comment: merging needs a lot of work though, questions need to be exactly the same (or edited to be the same, with examples retrofitted in the answers to reflect the question changes).

Answer (score 12):

Find/create a good canonical and close them as duplicate is the obvious move. However, be sure to treat each question on a **case by case basis.**

### Because two questions have the same title doesn't make them duplicates.

Quite often askers are not in the best position to put a good title on their questions, and multiple questions with approximately the same title could actually ask for very different things.

Here is a non exhaustive list of the kind of questions you may face during your task:

---

#### The common case.

Nothing fancy, a common set of constraints and a simple application; just what makes everyone struggling with the subject matter.
This will represent what 95% of users will want to find, this is the one that absolutely needs a good canonical because it will also be the one we'll see the most.

If we keep OP's original request, that would be all the questions that read

> ***How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?***
>
> I have a <canvas> relatively positioned in my page that can scroll...

There are multiple possible answers to this question, and all have their merit. So it's important they are all accessible under the same post.

**=> close as dupe of the canonical.**

---

#### The (less-common) obvious case.

There may be some special case which make the *common case* solutions not fit perfectly because the situation has less restrictive constraints.
In OP's case that would be questions like

> ***How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?***
>
> I have a full-screen <canvas>...

Here I'd personally say that the *common case* may still help, and unless there is a clear mention that they don't want it (e.g because *they don't want the overhead of grabbing the relative position of the element*), then closing as dupe of the canonical is still ok. (You may want to add a comment explaining your rational / asking them if they absolutely want the particular case).

---

#### The above common case

This is where the common case isn't enough because the situation involves some stronger constraints.

For instance that could be

> ***How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?***
>
> I made my own projection system, however I fail to link it correctly with the mouse events...

*(A real-life example is [OP's own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654650/) which does have a better title than the average, but still...)*

Most often, the *common case* is already known, and correctly applied here.
Closing as dupe of the *common case* is thus utterly wrong in these cases.

---

#### The debugging case

This one is where the asker actually didn't need at all what their title asks, but because that's what they were doing at this time, it's what they gave us.

A common example would be

> ***How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?***
>
> I used the code from /questions/3141592653 but it doesn't work. The console keep saying "*Can't call method getBoundingClientRect of null*"...

These questions most probably already have canonical, but it's not the one of the *common case*.
So edit their title if possible, vote to close accordingly, but do not mark them as duplicate of "How to do X". That's not what they are about.