# Duplicate answer flag rejected

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Recently while doing my daily runs through the review queue I stumbled upon a suspicious [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56414550/5759072) in the "Late Answers" queue. After further investigation I quickly concluded that the answer is a blatant *copy-paste* duplicate of an already [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295074/5759072) in the same question:

[image: Accepted answer]
[image: Offending answer]

Now the these two answers are *technically* not identical as the user provides a snippet of information about a `SQL` dialects being removed and slightly reformulates the original answer, but at the every least the flag acceptable for this answer should fall into the category of *not an answer*, because the information should be provided as a comment rather then an full fledged answer to a question that has been dead for over 2 years.

So in any case, like any good SO user I decided to flag it, but I didn't know exactly which flag to use so I went with the **in need of moderator intervention** flag. I described the flag as such:

> This answer is a copy-paste duplicate of an already existing answer.

Shortly after I went through my flag history to check up on some things and I've noticed that the flag was rejected for the following reason:

> declined - A moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

According to this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/5759072) the user has violated license [CC by-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/):

> If a user posts an answer that plagiarizes someone else's answer, they have violated the license under which that original answer was contributed, specifically the part that requires attribution.
>
> The same applies to content copied from elsewhere; posting someone else's work without clear attribution should be flagged. Even if there is a license that permits you to copy without attribution, passing off the works of others as your own, on a platform that rewards you for your work, is not appreciated.

I've taken this issue to the [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) in hopes of getting a better picture of what's going on and their response seems to corroborate my suspicions that the mysterious moderator most probably made a mistake and overlooked the answer the offending answer plagiarized.

Maybe I am not seeing something quite obvious but can someone please explain to me why my flag was rejected, when it is a clear-cut case of plagiarism? If anyone can take a closer look at this issue and provide some feedback as to what I did wrong I would much appreciate it.

*Note that I am not asking for an appeal or for the moderator in question be flogged and dragged through the virtual streets of Stack Exchange, just for an explanation of why this has happened so I can improve my moderating skills as a new contributor.*

**EDIT:** I've been advised in SOCVR to downvote the answer and provide an appropriate comment, so I have done so to inform the user about this issue. To be honest I should have done this earlier but I thought it was going to get quickly removed so I abstained, it will not happen again.

Comment: In this case, plagiarism is difficult to prove because there's so little there. It's just one line, with 3 parts: an XML tag, a `name`, and a value. It isn't an exact copy/paste, so it could just as easily be the kind of difference you get from two people providing the same short answer rather than copying. There's not enough evidence here to break the assumption of good faith. A "blatant copy-paste duplicate" would need to be a literal copy. And this isn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas I would agree with you if offending answer was not made 2 years after the accepted answer. The user clearly read the accepted answer then proceeded to write his answer as a slight modification of the accepted one. I am relatively new to SO so I though this was considered unacceptable, but it would seem such behavior is encouraged here. I learn as I go.

Comment: We don't agree that it was a modification at all. We're saying that your evidence that the answerer copies the answer is insufficiently conclusive.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hm, I am not well versed in mysql, but what you are saying is that those two answers are completely different from one another?

Comment: That question assumes a binary condition: either they're completely different or "blatant copy-paste duplicate". I don't accept that binary condition. It seems to me that the question is simple enough that all correct answers would have substantial similarities. Therefore, being similar isn't enough to assume plagiarism.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's fair, I agree.

Comment: What you wrote in your flag "This answer is a copy-paste duplicate of an already existing answer." is lacking a very important thing: an actual link to what you feel was copied. You should *not* make moderators have to go try to find what you think was copied based off of a minimal description. Whenever possible, you should link to the source of what you feel was plagiarized.

Comment: What @Makyen said. I've been seeing a *lot* of flags over the past week or so that simply say "duplicate of existing answer". *Which* existing answer? I have no idea. Making matters worse, these low-effort flags are often raised on Q&A with tens of answers. I'm not going to read them all to try and figure out which one of the 30 answers you meant, so I decline. If you're going to raise a custom flag, you need to actually use that textbox to provide us with information. At a *minimum*, include a link to the existing answer. Better, explain how the one you flagged adds nothing new to the Q&A.

Answer (score 22):

We have to redefine blatant.

Accepted answer:

> in your CFG file please change the hibernate dialect
>
> ```
> <!-- SQL dialect -->
>     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
> ```

The answer you flagged:

> Dialects are removed in recent SQL so use
>
> ```
> <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect"/>
> ```

The newer answer tries to explain why that config change is needed. It also has a slightly different value. That is not a blatant copy.

On top of that the answer wasn't down voted at the time it came to my attention in SOCVR, nor did it had any comments. The answer did pass through [3 queues](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56414550/timeline).

Your custom mod flag said:

> This answer is a copy-paste duplicate of an already existing answer.

So what? When the mod did the same compare as I (and [Stephen Kennedy](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46385813#46385813)) did they could only conclude that wasn't the case.
And what action do you expect from the mod and why? Deletion? Verify if the OP did post more of these "blatant copies"? In your mod flag not only state verifiable facts but include why it jeopardizes content quality, what action you want the mod to take and why you think the community will not be able to reach the same outcome.

**tl;dr:** It is an answer so it is most likely not going to get removed by any of the standard flags. The answer isn't a blatant one-on-one copy (yes, we do see that as well) so calling it plagiarized isn't a strong case, specially when there is only one or two lines to go on. What you should have done as a minimum is: down vote, leave comment explaining why the answer isn't adding anything new.

The custom mod flagged was poorly phrased to start with but even if it was phrased better I still think the answer shouldn't be deleted. It adds just that bit of info that puts it out of the Not An Answer league.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, answers that are copies of other answers with only slight modifications are acceptable as long as they bring any new information?

Comment: @Matthew yes. And specially if it is on the same question.

Comment: Is there an established measure of acceptable threshold for how much you are allowed to copy from another answer. Would 99% constitute an offense? Please don't take this as mocking or something of that sort, I am genuinely interested in knowing this as I am likely to stumble upon more of these situations in the future.

Comment: @Matthew there is no such threshold and having one doesn't make sense. I have flagged (successfully) plagiarized answers that contained verbatim copies of three sources from within and outside of Stack Overflow. When flagging answers *on the same question* it starts to count when it is an 100% copy **and** the posts are 6 to 8 weeks apart.

Comment: Okay, so another answer that is a 100% copy of other answers is acceptable as long as it has been posted after 6 to 8 weeks have passed since the original answer has been posted. I definitely did not know that, could you provide a reference that states this requirement?

Comment: @Matthew no, that is not what I meant. Same answers on a question do happen. Assume good faith and use votes and comments before anything else. Timing is an important factor ([6 to 8 weeks is a meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)). When in any doubt, don't flag.

Comment: Alright this seems to be a grey area, so for the sake of not running into these kind of problems again I will just assume every answer as not being a duplicate under every circumstance. Thank you for all the answers, I now better understand this topic.

Comment: @Matthew Are you really so opposed to ever having a moderator not agree with you that you'd not flag stuff you're highly confident is problematic because you're unwilling to have someone disagree with you?  Just flag instances where you think in good faith there's a problem, and gracefully accept the fact that some of those will turn out to not in fact be problematic, when a moderator looks into it in more depth.

Comment: @Servy I believe there is way too much instances where I believe something should not be on SO but most disagree with me. You're looking at this the wrong way, look at it like this: *Why would I burden the moderators with reviewing flags that I SUSPECT will mostly likely be rejected when I can just not raise them?*

Comment: @Matthew There's a huge difference between flagging something you wished weren't on the site, but that you know doesn't break any rules, versus flagging something where there's some room for interpretation, and that is not a strictly black and white decision for all involved, where different people will disagree on whether or not it breaks the rules.  Don't flag the former, as it's just wasting people time, always flag the latter, and don't worry if it doesn't pan out the way you wanted it to.

Comment: @Matthew So to bring it back to this case, rather than generalizing, you should be flagging posts *that you suspect were in fact plagiarized*, and not worry about it if a moderator feels there's insufficient evidence to act on it, but you shouldn't be flagging answers for simply having similar (but clearly independently created) solutions to a problem.

Comment: @Servy What I gathered from this post it would seem that in most cases I should give the benefit of the doubt even if I have high suspicions that it indeed was plagiarized, and intend to do just that. I don't understand what's with all the fuss about this?

Comment: @Matthew What you were told was that two different answers that had strong indications they were independently arrived at, and that even provide different information are not at all worthy of deletion, and your response was to say you'll just never flag anything for plagiarism because it's not black and white.  That one case has compelling evidence it's not plagiarism doesn't mean you shouldn't ever flag plagiarism.

Comment: @Servy As I've explained in this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385693/duplicate-answer-flag-rejected/385694?noredirect=1#comment701033_385698) I just feel that I don't have enough experience to make a good determination on what is and what isn't plagiarism since I am new to the site.

Answer (score 14):

I've declined quite a few 'duplicate answer' flags over the last few days.

We don't police content that covers the same ground as other content.  That's up to you, the person who votes.

We do police copyright infringement and plagiarism, however.  Both of those require a level of similarity that far surpasses covering the same ground in content.

If it's not a word for word copy, or it's not demonstrable that the content is copied from another source without attribution, we're going to decline the flag and have the community handle the content on its own.

Answer (score 11):

We're getting a lot of "duplicate answers" flags. Reading this meta post [How to handle duplicate answer cleanup on popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385063/how-to-handle-duplicate-answer-cleanup-on-popular-questions) helped me with how to handle those.

Meta answers state that if the answer adds something (or is different), we should keep it. Make sure that the "duplicate" answer is a subset/combination of solutions found in earlier answers.

It's *not* the case here (I don't know the technology, but there *are* differences)

So maybe you could have been lucky if the moderator who handled your flag was an expert and estimated that it was the same thing, but in the other cases, especially with a one-liner answer the moderator just blindly compares, sometimes using "search" as exact text (that's what I do on non-Python duplicate flagged answers).

If the text doesn't match exactly (here it's matching `MySQL5Dialect` against `MySQL57Dialect`), I'd decline the flag and give the answer the benefit of doubt (of course if the code is a copy/paste of 50 lines with just one modified variable name, that's another story).

What also "helps" me to decline the flag is when the answer doesn't have a single downvote, not even from the user who flagged it...

Comment: I've concluded the easiest thing for those new to the moderation queue like myself is to just not flag content I think is a duplicate of some sort. This way I am avoiding potentially burdening the queue with false flags, as determining what is a duplicate and what is not on SO seems to be a very delicate affair.

Comment: wise decision. That said, I appreciate being shown real copy/paste (or opportunistic) answers on very old & popular questions. Some should read previous answers before answering the exact same thing, even if it's not copy paste.