# What did I do wrong? My answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Link of my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65236800/14762762

[image]

Please I need an answer. I don't know why.

Comment: It looks to add no information over the top answer (with 113 votes) nor the second top answer (11 votes). Posting new answers that cover no new ground years after other answers have been posted do not help anyone, and should be deleted (or not posted in the first place).

Comment: How does it differ from the [highest scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606098/215552), or the [second highest scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59037748/215552)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance  But this is not a good reason to delete an answer that has more than 4 votes. This is not logical.  Besides my answer was more detailed.

Comment: It doesn't look more detailed to me. The number of votes the answer got before being deleted is irrelevant. People posting answers like these results in a [long tail of crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390907) that benefits no one.

Comment: You've asked why is was deleted. People explained this. You're unlikely to "get it back" since everyone seem to agree that it's not adding any value to the thread. Perhaps the best thing you can do now is to understand and accept that. Generally when posting Answers, it's a good idea to read the entire thread first and then make sure that what you want to add is either a different perspective or something new.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think on stackoverflow everyone tries to give an answer that they find easier. If the first answer was better than mine nobody would have up-voted my answer.

Comment: See the [question I just linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390907) - *Mysteriously, those late answers can somehow gather many upvotes even if they are not adding any useful content, they're sometimes even voted up when obviously incorrect, so the usual quality controls of downvotes and delvotes are not proving adequate.*

Comment: Your time is better spent answering new questions than bumping this one.

Comment: At the end of the day, if your answer is really more detailed than other answers on a question with many other answer, make the extra detail(s)/ difference(s) *very* explicit; this should help avoid future deletions like this one.

Answer (score 16):

That question seems to receive a lot of activity and in particular a lot of answers that don't add a lot of value to what's already there. Your answer may be "more detailed", but it seems to read as simply a wordier version of what's already there, including what I assume is a footnote formatted as a blockquote for some reason. Not entirely sure what the image is adding either. If anything that footnote was the only differentiator in your answer.

I'm not very compelled to undelete your answer to this question. I suggest focusing on new questions or questions that haven't been answered.

Comment: (It has a high view rate of 53 views/day, but it is not in [the top 100 for Flutter questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164178/highest-view-rate-questions-in-a-particular-tag-non-community-wiki) by this measure (the top 100 has 92 - 416 views/day). It is a power law, so it is probably not in the top 200.)