# How about adding a "duplicate answer" manual flag type?

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-answers, custom-flags

In a previous [How to handle cleanup of late blatantly duplicate answers ('surfing') on popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385063/how-to-handle-cleanup-of-late-blatantly-duplicate-answers-surfing-on-popular) question, we got answers encouraging users to flag copied/duplicate answers and moderators to delete them.

That's pretty fine. But the way it is done isn't always optimal because it involves *custom moderator flags*.

Custom moderator flags are the most time consuming flags that a mod can handle. Specially because the users who flag can provide a lot of links/details, or they also can write a very vague description.

In the case of duplicated answers, there are a lot of custom flags stating "this is a duplicate answer". Now go figure which answer this answer duplicates... Specially if the moderator looking at the flag doesn't know the technology. So the moderator must open the page containing the question and read all the answers / search for the answer which is supposed to have been copied. Sometimes it's obvious, sometimes not.

Given that that case happens very often, I suggest a new flag type: duplicate answer.

When using that kind of flag, the flagger would have to:

- add a link to the "original" answer
- provide a small text justifying the duplication, if this isn't obvious.

If that was implemented, the moderator could check the similarities way more quickly and besides that would allow moderator UI a chance to:

- implement a nice interface to show both answers side by side
- add an automatic comment when validating the flag/deleting the answer: this is mostly copied/a duplicate of this answer:

Some may say that it's a feature only useful for a handful of people (us, the moderators), but it's not: custom flags are the most difficults flags to process, so that flag type would not go in that category, and even without extra help from the UI, the flag would take way less time to be processed.

Note: there is already a "duplicate answer" flag in the moderator UI, but it's an automatic flag that detects same exact answer posted by the same user. Very useful, but doesn't help here.

Comment: Related: [this post by Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384812/)

Comment: I would suggest a more generic solution like adding predefined tags to custom flag so moderator can easily sort them on their side ([vauting fraud], [duplicate answer] [plagiarism], etc) and maybe we also add a language related tag with it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif well, maybe now that's too much categorization. But the "plagiarism" flag requiring a link could be implemented almost the same way. Voting fraud we can handle by a custom flag.

Comment: yes but I meant that inside the actual custom flag feature we have those tags so on your side you can easily filter them instead of adding a new flag type. The custom flag will cover everything and the tag will help in the categorization.

Comment: you obviously haven't seen mod ui :)

Answer (score 33):

I was about to post a similar request when I was handed a link to this one. I fully support and agree with this request but with a twist:

***Why even "bother" moderators with such flags?***

I think that we should have such a flag, but not have it go directly to the moderators dash, but rather to a ***review queue*** - be it a new one or somehow use the existing Low Quality Answers queue (maybe with a small banner "this answer was flagged as a duplicate").

I encounter a lot of this kind of answers and I feel that it is not necessary to "bother" (and wait for) a mod to handle, and that it can be easily handled by the community.

To my knowledge, a NAA flag puts the answer in the LQA review queue, and only after some
time it will appear in the moderators dash as well. I think a similar scheme can be easily applied here. First let the community a chance to handle the flag, and if it doesn't manage to - it will be handled by the mods eventually.

Comment: good idea. sometimes we need expert eyes for some not so obvious duplicate content

Comment: I somewhat agree with this, but I also can foresee regular users just getting a lot of things wrong (like all the other queues). It would certainly take significantly longer to handle if left to a review queue.

Comment: I know this might seem radical, but... why not use the same process for duplicate answers that we use for duplicate questions?

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to add support for this idea, including [this amendment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412641/861716) (direct the flag to the review queue), from a user perspective.

Duplicated answers are an annoying phenomenon on Stack Overflow. They add noise, while Stack Overflow's core mission is all about reducing noise. So whenever I see a duplicate answer I try to do something about it. But I'm still not sure about the best course of action.

It seems that the majority of this type of answers is posted by low-rep users, probably just trying to emphasize a helpful answer, not being able to upvote or comment. Such users typically don't respond to comments or downvotes. The result is a downvoted answer that just sits there for ages to come.

I always try to avoid raising a custom flag, because I know they considerably increase the moderators' work load. But two other flags, "not an answer" and "low quality", don't cover this type of answer—they do answer the question (the answerer may not even be aware of posting a duplicate) and they may be more than just an unexplained code fragment or one-liner.

Still, I sometimes use one of these flags, leaving a comment that's really more targeted to people in the review queue than to the answerer, and hope for the best. I see others do the same thing. But these flags are easily disputed or even declined because of users (or mods) applying the flag reasons more strictly (which I understand). I don't like to get disputed or declined flags added to my flags history, but more than that, I don't like to see these answers survive.

So, yes please, a "duplicate answer" flag type, to be dealt with in the low quality answers review queue.

Comment: Well, there is always SOCVR as an option when you see a duplicated answer. But yeah, an in-built way of dsaling with those would be nice. Granted, that's unlikely to happen (SE doing *anything* for curators is extremely unlikely), but a man can dream, I guess...

Comment: @OlegValter In my experience, SOCVR is great for easy decisions, not for ones that require content knowledge. Closing question as duplicate is far less successful there than closing for more obvious reasons like missing an MRE or being off-topic.

Comment: Yeah, but I had enough success cleaning up duplicate answers there to suggest SOCVR as an option - I did not mean it's *the* option, but it is viable. I would much rather have a dedicated flag type, of course, but alas.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine small caveat here is that SOCVR is only helpful for <0 scored answers (which surely are the majority). For the less frequent case of higher scored duplicates only a mod can delete (I did get to flag a 60+ scored duplicate).

Answer (score -4):

Would there be benefit to extending the proposed flag to duplicate answers across multiple questions? I can see three possible scenarios for duplicate answers across questions:

1. Non-duplicate questions, duplicate answers; the answer is valid for both questions.
2. Non-duplicate questions, duplicate answers; the answer isn't valid for one of the questions.
3. Duplicate questions with duplicate answers.

The proposal obviously covers duplicate answers on a single question. If the duplicate answers are valid for both questions (#1), then they shouldn't be flagged.

The other two scenarios already have existing handling mechanisms -- downvoting/closing (#2), and flagging as a duplicate question (#3); so perhaps an additional flag on the answer isn't useful.

OTOH, the proposed flag could serve as a pointer to the other problems (duplicate question, bad answer), and would thus provide value.

Comment: it's still potentially plagiarism in all three cases, whether it's a valid answer or not.

Comment: @Zoe While plagiarism is certainly a concern, my first perception of the issue is that the same content exists in multiple places, and edits / updates to one will not be reflected in the other. That negative would need to be balanced against the positive of being a valid answer to the non-duplicate question.