# Add an option for "it's a duplicate answer" when recommending deletion on Late answers review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, late-answers

When I'm reviewing in the "Late answers" queue, I usually check if the answer is a duplicate of an existing answer on the question.

If it is, I use this option:

[image: Image of the recommend deletion option from the queue]

Because, as mentioned, *it's a duplicate*.

But when I do it, there isn't any "This is a duplicate of an answer" option:

[image: Image of all the possible options for recommend deletion]

So every time I go back, leave a comment such as *"Thanks for your answer, there already exist one or more answers to this question that say exactly the same"*. Finally, I use "No comment needed".

But, all people that will see this report will not necessarily understand that it's a duplicate answer.

How to solve this?

Why not make something like when I report a duplicate answer: select (at least one) other answer which is similar, and choose such as we do for duplicate question?

Also, to go further, why don't add an option "Duplicate answer" when flagging an answer such as "not an answer" everywhere ?

Comment: On a side note, I find it very disappointing that they tell a user that obviously did not read the help to click on the "Ask Question" button. It's going to make more user ask without knowing how the site works.

Comment: I agree with you.. sort of. But with those comments that would say, "this is what this other Answer says", it would be preferable to link to the other Answer, and instead put "this is what [this other Answer](<directly link>) says". That will require you post a manual comment. If you already isolated which other Answer it is, then why not make it easier for anyone else that comes across the post?

Comment: I find it quite puzzling that the dev team explicitly stated that they will change the Late Answers queue to support removal of duplicated answers but all they did is make the Late Answers queue a duplicate in itself of the Low Quality Posts (Answers) queue. They just used the exact same modal for recommend deletion... I like your suggestion for picking the specific answer it is duplicating. That could create a canned comment with a link to that answer to further help future reviewers

Comment: When there is over 20 answer, and 10 are the same, that unreadable and difficult to find the one that will solve our issue. I think it's better to have 3 answer that resume possible fix than 12 answer when each possible fix are duplicate

Comment: This is especially frustrating when the text for the "Looks OK" button explicitly asks you to check that the answer *is not a duplicate*.

Comment: The actual text on the "Looks OK" button is: *Answer addresses the question, **is unique,** and is not low quality.* (I had already exhausted my quota when I posted that comment yesterday, and I have the memory of a dereferenced void* pointer.)

Comment: And it's clearly dangerous : I have been banned from review just because I flag as "recommand deletion -> no comment" [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29870740) because it's EXACTLY the copy of the main answer...

Comment: Seems to me there could be a free-form comment box _right in_ the selection list there. "Other issue / Leave a comment for the author explaining the issue with their answer. [input box]". Is there some reason that's _not_ encouraged?

Comment: @Elikill58: While I like the idea of building this in, remember you aren’t limited to the canned responses. When flagging or voting to delete duplicates, I always leave a comment pointing back to the answer it’s duplicating—if only as a sign post for other reviewers. In fact, I do that with any flag or vote that might not be immediately obvious to a casual reviewer or busy moderator (e.g., text copied wholesale without credit, using an entirely different programming language, an answer that’s commenting on another answer, &c.). That helps avoid false negatives that might lead to a ban.

Comment: @FeRD: I like that idea. It could even limit the length to carve out space for adding the “—[from review](https://stackoverflow.com)” link, which is otherwise lost for custom comments today.

Comment: I totally agree, and add an option to say "it's a duplicate answwer", and we have to select the other answer such as when flagging as duplicate question (and use it in the comment).

Comment: A year later nothing has changed. Dunno, I'll just skip duplicate answers then.

Comment: I just earned the review privilege and my first late answer suffers from this problem, but I can't properly delete it. Please fix this or it will be really annoying to try to use my shiny new privilege.

Comment: @Sinc Gg for your reputation ! For the post, it's not even at status-review. Idk when they will check for it, maybe never but it's sad

Comment: See also [How about adding a "duplicate answer" manual flag type?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398644/how-about-adding-a-duplicate-answer-manual-flag-type).

Answer (score 6):

Another problem with the same dialogue is there is no option to add a custom comment.

My work around was to cancel the *"Add a comment ..."* dialogue, then use the *"Add a comment"* link near the bottom of the review page. Finally click *"Recommend deletion"* again and choose *"No comment needed"*.

Comment: I also mentioned this in the above comments in response to @FeRD, but to reiterate here: This could even limit the length to carve out space for adding the “—[from review](https://stackoverflow.com)” link, which is otherwise lost for custom comments today.