How should I handle an answer that appears to be "Looks OK" but in fact is not really unique or distinct from the existing answers?
In the First Answers Queue here on Stack Overflow, I came across an answer that seemed to be Looks OK in all respects, however, it did not seem to add anything new. The question was also only asked three days ago. The answer did however repeat the code that the OP gave and made changes to it (the other answers only showed one line snippets) and the answerer added a few lines of explanation.
However, since I am not very experienced with the First Answers Queue, I decided to check the help and I read:

Review the “Other answers” tab (if it exists) to confirm that the answer is unique and distinct from the existing answers to the question.

Having read that, I felt that I should not mark this as Looks OK, but there does not appear to be any other suitable option.
I thought that maybe I should mark it as: Answer needs supporting information and perhaps it does, but if it were not for the other answers then this should probably be marked as Looks OK
I think the problem I have with the help given above is the phrase "unique and distinct".
Should I interpret "unique and distinct" as "not being a close copy"?

Background Information
This is the reviewed answer that triggered this question for me.
This is not a duplicate of What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)? because that question deals with the concept of late answers. In this particular question, the answer was being reviewed in the First Answer Review Queue and was the second answer posted (and there were three other answers). In addition, the length of time between the posting of the question and the final edit of the reviewed answer was less than ten minutes.
It is important to also note the posting and editing times of the question and its answers:



Post
Activity
Time




Question
posted
16:21:35


Answer 1
posted
16:25:03


Answer 2 (the reviewed answer)
posted
16:25:38


Answer 2 (the reviewed answer)
deleted
16:26:36


Answer 2 (the reviewed answer)
undeleted
16:26:49


Answer 2 (the reviewed answer)
first edit
16:28:36


Answer 2 (the reviewed answer)
second edit
16:29:17


Answer 2 (the reviewed answer)
final edit
16:29:38


Answer 1
first and only edit, i.e. the final edit
16:30:05


Answer 3
posted
16:32:52


Answer 3
first and only edit, i.e. the final edit
16:33:56


Answer 4
posted
11:17:55 on the next day



Interestingly, going back to the advice given in the help, namely:

Review the “Other answers” tab (if it exists) to confirm that the answer is unique and distinct from the existing answers to the question.

We can see that the phrase from the existing answers also needs to be clarified. It is clear from the analysis of the timeline given in the table above that Answers 3 and 4 were posted after the final edit of Answer 2, and even though they exist at the time of the review, they did not exist at the time when editing of Answer 2 was finally completed.
Again, interestingly, the answers on the "Other answers" tab in the First Answers Review Queue are presented in  Highest Score order (without positioning the reviewed answer among the other answers) and there is no option to change to a date order.
How should we deal with duplicate answers? is interesting, especially this answer which discusses the Fastest Gun In The West problem.

I think you can vote and/or flag (or event comment), and then choose "other action".

Should I interpret "unique and distinct" as "not being a close copy" I personally think that fits quite well, doesn't it? If the answer adds something unique to it from other answers, I believe it deserves to stay most of the time, unless the unique part is merely one sentence, in which case extending an existing answer is probably more useful.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136668/356669

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411138/add-an-option-for-its-a-duplicate-answer-when-recommending-deletion-on-late-a

Underneath the answer is the flag link. Identify an answer that you think already covered this answer, and then raise a moderator flag to note that you think the answer is just covering what that answer covered already. Note that this applies to answers made some time later after the duplicate answer. Answers made close to the posting of the question are not subject to this rule.
Once you have mod flagged, select the "Other action" option to complete the review.

Note one thing: review audits. To generate "known-good" audits in the FA queue (and LA and LQA queues), the system will take a highly-voted existing answer and fake the authorship to make it look like it was posted recently by a new user. There are plenty of users who've failed audits after following the link to the question, seeing the same answer posted a while ago by a high-rep user, and flagging the answer as an exact copy-paste. Make sure you use the "Other answers" tab in the review itself rather than following the link to the question to avoid this.

(But that's still not a complete solution. Some users may recognize the answer after having previously read it on the question.)
