# Plagiarism flag and moderator tooling has launched to Stack Overflow!

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism, moderator-tools

We're excited to share that we've launched a new suite of tools to help users and moderators on Stack Overflow handle plagiarized questions, answers, and articles. We've been working on this in collaboration with the community here and moderators, who got a preview of the UI and gave us a lot of helpful feedback in early February. For more background on this, please see the prior discussions on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [We need a dedicated plagiarism flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381806/we-need-a-dedicated-plagiarism-flag)
- [Feedback request: Proposed new flagging and moderation workflow for plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383589/feedback-request-proposed-new-flagging-and-moderation-workflow-for-plagiarism)

**The (long) TL;DR is that we're adding:**

- New flag type - "Plagiarized content" - for questions, answers, and articles
- Flag handling UI for moderators and other minor UI improvements for users' flagged posts page
- Automatic removal of reputation for old, high-scoring posts deleted as plagiarism (while deleted)
- Post notices to identify plagiarized content (while deleted) and guide authors on how to fix it
- Post history notices when posts are flagged or deleted as plagiarism

### Flagging UI - a new flag type

When a user finds a post that is plagiarized and wants to raise a flag, they've had to use the "In need of moderator intervention" option. This results in slow handling of non-plagiarism moderator intervention flags as mods aren't able to separate out plagiarism flags to focus on. As such, we're adding a new flag reason for plagiarism. It'll be the last standard flag reason.

[image: New flag option for users "Plagiarised content" it has information about when to raise a plagiarism flag and gives fields for links to the source content and an explanation.]

In this form, both fields are required, but the link does not have to be a URL. That being said, URLs are highly encouraged as it's difficult for a moderator to confirm the content is plagiarized if they can not see the original source.

### Moderator Flag handling

Posts flagged for this reason will appear as a separate flag type in the flag dashboard for moderators and give them plagiarism-specific options to handle the flag, which is the same whether the flags are being handled on the mod dashboard or directly on the post.

Per mod feedback, we wanted to keep the behavior as consistent as possible with the current behavior and avoid surprising mods when they're handling these flags.

- They have the new option "Delete as plagiarism" which will delete the post, mark the flag helpful, and remove the reputation earned for the post, even if it would otherwise have been retained.
- Marking a flag as "helpful" will validate the flag but not delete the post, mods may explain their reasons for marking helpful.
- Declining the flag will remove it and the moderator will need to explain their reasoning for declining the flag.
- Using the standard UI deletion buttons will cause the post to be deleted normally.

To avoid removing content that might be particularly useful and worth fixing rather than deleting, we will be showing a notice to mods in the following cases:

- **Answers**: top-scoring answer with a score of >3
- **Questions**: score of >3 that is still open

These will look like this:

[image: Modal titled "Delete post" with the text "Are you sure you want to delete this plagiarized post? This post has a score of 7 and may be useful to the community. Instead of deleting, you may raise a CM escalation to request a post disassociation, which will retain the post and remove the reputation from the user."]

We did get feedback from some moderators that this might slow down their actions and get in the way. However, we believe that the changes we've made to only show this in specific cases will make it less likely to be shown unless the post is truly valuable and will only appear in cases where the user would lose reputation they wouldn't have otherwise lost.

We'll definitely be considering this carefully to see how frequently it appears and whether it does cause issues for moderators.

#### Moderators flagging posts for plagiarism

Moderators can also flag the post as plagiarism if they come across it without it having been flagged by a user - which is common in cases of mass plagiarism by one user across many of their posts. Doing so will raise a flag but not immediately handle it, so this will be a two-step process. The mod will first raise the flag to mark the post as plagiarism and then handle it.

This is a place where we got a lot of feedback from the mods about concerns regarding slowing down the process. We understand the concerns and we've decided to ship this as a two-step process primarily because we wanted to avoid surprising mods. While it's true that spam and rude flags immediately handle the flag and delete the post, "moderator attention" flags do not, so there's not one consistent behavior. Because these flags resemble mod attention flags more closely, we're opting to start out with the two-step process and see what the experience is like directly.

Additionally, the process can get somewhat unwieldy when you add together all of the elements into a single step. We have to tack on a bunch of additional checks before the deletion actually goes through - mostly relating to the special casing for removing reputation when posts are deleted as plagiarism and the warnings we're showing in the cases described above.

### Post notices and post history

Posts deleted as plagiarism will get a post notice indicating the reason for deletion that is visible to both [high-reputation users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and the OP, though there are two variations depending on who's seeing the notice.

The OP will see a longer explanation (first one below). This has links to various guidance about why the post was [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions), how to properly [cite information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), and encourages the OP to edit the post to improve it (opens the editor).

The shorter variation is shown to moderators and anyone else who can see the deleted post.

[image: Two post notices in one box. The lower one says "This post is hidden. It was flagged as plagiarism and deleted just now." The upper one says the same thing, and continues "To request undeletion, edit your post to reference all content written by others and then flag the post "in need of moderator intervention".]

Unlike most deleted post notices, these do not attribute the deletion to anyone in particular. This is similar to how we're not showing the list of close voters to the asker in the post notice.

We discussed having a link to the original content in these post notices as that was one of the asks for this but decided not to include it in this variation. When we were working on the designs for this, we weren't sure how to display the link, particularly in cases where there isn't one or there are multiple links without opening a can of worms of complexity. If we see this isn't working, we can always consider improving that workflow.

Additionally, we've ensured that post history events for both the deletion and flagging are clear and easy to read for whoever can see them. The flag history event includes the flag type and both the flag fields while the deletion reason says "as plagiarism". As with other post history events, plagiarism deletions *are* attributed to the moderator who deleted the post.

[image: Screenshot showing an example of a post that was deleted as plagiarism and flagged as plagiarism by a moderator. It shows several columns on a post history page indicating the action that was taken and by whom.]

### Launch and feedback

Between community discussion, moderator review, and internal testing, we're confident that you will all find the new plagiarism workflow a significant improvement from the existing system. We will also consider updates as we release and gather feedback. Once live, we hope you will use it when necessary and let us know about your experience - both positive and negative - in the answers below.

If you run into any bugs, please do your best to explain them along with how to reproduce them if possible. If you are struggling with the new workflow, please help us understand your difficulties by talking about the problems you're having rather than focusing too much on solutions. As I've mentioned a couple of times in this post, we expect we may run into some places where this process isn't optimized and we're willing to make improvements where necessary.

### Thanks!

A huge amount of gratitude goes out to the moderators here on SO for helping us understand the problems and know how to support these changes. We also appreciate all of the community members who have been giving feedback throughout this process. Thanks so much for your patience while we got this planned and built.

Also, this project couldn't have been done without the support of the awesome Community Enablement pod, who focus on building tools for Mods and CMs. The PM, designers, devs and other team members have done an amazing job digging into and understanding the needs of this project. Thanks and credit for so much of this goes to them! Also to Bella_Blue, my partner in plagiarism on the CM team for working with me to communicate so much of this to you all.

Comment: Quick question. If a post is suspected of being plagiarized from ChatGPT, can we flag for plagiarism and write ChatGPT in the source, or should we continue using mod flags?

Comment: I guess I'm in the minority, as in all my years here I've rarely notice plagiarized questions or answers. Could probably count them on one hand.

Comment: @Fastnlight I'd leave that for the mods to answer, honestly. That's more of a site policy decision than I feel comfortable making. :)

Comment: @Fastnlight I'd still use a custom flag for ChatGPT answers at this stage.

Comment: Posting as a comment as I'm not in a position to vocalise in an answer properly, but disassociation for upvoted plagiarism feels "wrong"; plagiarism is plagiarism and it shouldn't be validated by the fact that it was well received.

Comment: @ThomA That's a point I should perhaps have clarified somewhat but, to be clear, when we retain information that has been plagiarised, the process involves editing the content to be clearly cited and sourced, linking to the original. The purpose of disassociation is to remove any benefits of the high-scoring content from the person who posted it on the site. :) That's where the "worth fixing" part of that paragraph comes in.

Comment: @j08691 - I see more plagiarized content then spam on a daily basis. A user will sometimes submit 10-15 answers and every single one of them will be plagiarized.

Comment: @SecurityHound I've noticed my ChatGPT answers than plagiarism

Comment: @j08691 - I consider ChatGPT answers to be a form of plagiarism, so double my numbers, since report a ton of ChatGPT answers. But plagiarism is a huge problem.

Comment: *New flag type - "Plagiarized content" - for questions, answers, and articles* — Dang, tag wikis have been forgotten yet again. Still, I'm glad to see this roll out, and I'm wondering if there are any plans to get it on other sites.

Comment: @Laurel you cannot flag tag wikis, though. The flag is being added to things that were already flaggable. Just a new entry in the flag list. Not saying tag wiki plagiarism shouldn't be considered an issue, just that we don't have facilities to signal for any problem with those.

Comment: When will this be available for other sites?

Comment: @j08691: Just look at late answers (to, say, popular questions). Any answer with complete English sentences is suspect. They are usually also quite verbose. Code dumps are also suspected to be the result of plagiarism, but it is very difficult to check.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch it's a site setting, so we can release it whenever a site indicates they want it changed but we'd need a meta discussion that indicates it's needed.

Comment: @Catija Why was it decided to make it opt-in for other sites rather than opt-out?

Comment: @gparyani because most other sites have no need for a custom flag for this. Either flag volume is so low it's not creating any issues for handling or there's almost never anything flagged as plagiarism. Adding flag reasons makes flagging harder, so we want to limit the number as much as reasonable.

Comment: When entirely plagiarized posts are edited to entirely correctly quoted posts, what is the official policy on all-quote posts being allowed & where is it given? Right now there is still the vague & somewhat obscurely located & inconsistently applied notion that that is discouraged & a moderator might delete such a post & a flag for that might or might not succeed. And please add appropriate mention/references in site plagiarism messaging/documentation.

Comment: "Automatic removal of reputation for old, high-scoring posts deleted as plagiarism (while deleted)" can I go back through my approved plagiarism flags over the past years and have the helpful ones adhere to this policy retroactively? I've flagged multiple 50+ scoring posts for plagiarism

Comment: @Adriaan I'd think so. Rep earned from plagiarism should be revoked, regardless of if the contributions are deleted before or after this new tooling.

Comment: @Adriaan While I can't expressly state that it's always the case, mods have generally reached out to the CMs to get high-scoring plagiarised posts disassociated from the poster, so I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @Catija does disassociation automatically revoke the reputation gained, even when the post was +3 and >90 days old when it was deleted?

Comment: @Adriaan Disassociation means that the post is no longer connected to their account - as such, the next time the rep recalculation runs, it will not find that post to include in the calculation. That's not precisely the same as revoking the reputation because it means the reputation never happened at all... but... yes.

Comment: @philipxy That's a question that's probably bigger than this specific discussion, so it might make sense as a new question. The current documentation does hedge as it says that mods may delete it rather than "will", but it often ends up being left to mod discretion. If it's helpful, these cases where disassociations happen to preserve high-scoring content are extremely rare. I've probably seen only 3-5 in the hundreds (thousands?) of cases of plagiarism mods have handled over the last few months.

Comment: If you're excited to try out this flag but don't know where to start, grab a sentence out of your favorite docs, put it in quotes in SO search, and see what comes up. (Whatever excitement I had about this has become the usual horror — more gets plagiarized than you realize.)

Comment: Are there any updates on [flagging duplicate answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398644/3169238)? From the comments on [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381806) I understand that plagiarism flag is __not__ for duplicate answers, but the only other option is a custom flag which still goes to the mods (plus I also leave a comment with text from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398644/3169238))

Comment: @SergeiKozelko Just to clarify, I believe the only open question is about better ways to handle **non-copy-pasted** duplicate answers, i.e., ones that don't add anything of substance compared to the previous answer(s). I would think **copy-pasted** duplicate answers are still flaggable as plagiarism. If not, they should probably mention that in the flagging modal because I'm pretty sure the average user will assume otherwise.

Comment: Great to know that! **One question.** What if the answer poster cites the site where they have plagiarized the answer?

Comment: @RohanBari if the poster clearly denotes the quoted parts and does their best to attribute it to the original author, then it's not plagiarism. However, just putting a link somewhere in the post isn't enough, because we all have the time to play detective, right?

Comment: "Plagiarism" is the appropriate flag for misappropriated content, since this covers generative content.

Comment: How can one clearly tell if the linked URL is newer or older than the answer? Seems like dates could easily be changed on sites that want to plagiarize FROM SE, accidentally making someone’s answer look like plagiarism. I’ve found it hard to tell whether a site copied SE or the SE answer plagiarized.

Comment: @Demis the internet archive will generally show the content. So if there's an entry in the archive prior to the SO post, it's older.

Comment: plagiarism will be a thing of the past now that ChatGPT is on the scene.  Just my two cents.

Comment: @java-addict301 On the contrary, ChatGPT has made plagiarism easier than ever.  We constantly see people post answers from it while failing to cite it as a source (and of course, it is unable to cite _its_ sources).

Comment: @RyanM is ChatGPT a source however? Or is it like your friend writing an answer for you? and what if the answer is from common knowledge (for AI, common knowledge could be everything).

Comment: @java-addict301 We do consider ChatGPT to be a source. Your friend is also a source: if they write an answer, they should do so from their own account (accounts should belong to one person), though realistically we're unlikely to catch this unless you have notably different writing styles (ChatGPT's writing style is pretty distinctive).  Note that in many cases, OpenAI also requires you to disclose the AI's involvement (["The role of AI in formulating the content is clearly disclosed in a way that no reader could possibly miss...
"](https://openai.com/policies/sharing-publication-policy)).

Comment: @java-addict301 [Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384647/241919) (it's moot on SO though since ChatGPT is temporarily banned)

Comment: Something not alone related to plagiarism, but often occurs with it, is that people receive a site association bonus by plagiarising content. Then the content and reputation of the question is removed, but the association bonus remains for example.

Answer (score 55):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Sources are treated as one giant link rather than detecting links like a normal flag

Here's an example of a flag on a plagiarized post with multiple sources:

[image: A plagiarism flag showing the phrase "https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086739 (prose), https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299259 (first code block), https://stackoverflow.com/a/11662989 (second code block)" as one giant link]

That link goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086739%20(prose),%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299259%20(first%20code%20block),%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/11662989%20(second%20code%20block), which is not especially helpful.  It also makes it more difficult to copy than if it weren't a link.  Could it perhaps just use the standard mini-Markdown parser that other flag text does?

Comment: This is fixed now. Links should be individually detected in the same way they do in the rest of the flag text. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 42):

A while ago, back when you announced your intent for this work, I [brought up concerns about the mod-ability to delete and revoke rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383591/622284) and requested that it be quite transparent that the deletion was specifically for plagiarism and that it was the only use for the delete-and-revoke-rep ability. Whether my feedback directly led to how transparent this delete-as-plagiarism tool is or not, I still want to say that I'm really happy how transparent this is in the timeline and deletion post notice.

These changes all look great, and I really appreciate all the work that went into this. I sincerely hope this helps with the workload that mods have here with plagiarism.

Comment: FWIW, I always expected this to be more visible than the old process (where the post was just deleted and sometimes disassociated). This was going to be a net increase in data on who did what and why. The Devs met those expectations and more.

Answer (score 28):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It is not possible to raise another type of flag in some conditions.

To reproduce:

- Click to flag a post.
- Select the "Plagiarised Content" flag type
- Enter the "Why do you consider this answer to be plagiarized?" text field
- Click one of the standard flags (Spam, Rude or abusive, Not an answer, or Very low Quality)

What happens:

- The "Flag answer" button is disabled until *another* standard flag type is selected.

A tl;dr image:

[image: See above]

It was reproduced in Firefox 110.0.1 and Edge 110.0.1587.63 on Windows 10, and Chrome 111.0.5563.58 on Android.

I've not fully explored the modal, so there might be other ways to reproduce it, but this bug is reproducible with my steps.

Comment: I can also reproduce this - thanks for reporting, looking into it now.

Comment: Okay, we found the issue and are working on a fix - it was an issue with our character counter still checking for validity even when that subform wasn't focused or expanded. We'll update this answer status once it's shipped, thanks again for the report.

Comment: Fix is shipped, should be live shortly.

Answer (score 27):

> In this form, both fields are required, but the link does not have to be a URL.

That's nice, since content can be plagiarized from non-Web sources, such as print sources like books as well as computerized content distributed offline (such as on CDs or USB flash drives).

However, the field in its current form *heavily implies* that the source must be a Web source. Its heading starts with "Link(s)" and the background text has "http://...".

Given the current UX, my initial inclination when stumbling upon plagiarism from a non-Web source would be to leave the field blank and explain the exact source (ISBN and page number of the book, the ChatGPT query that resulted in identical output, etc.) in the second (elaboration) field. But when I do so, I'd get an error message that both fields must be filled in. That would be frustrating and I'd be more inclined to either use a custom flag or just leave the post as is.

Please make it **exceptionally clear** that the field is not *only* for URLs but is freeform. Example text:

> ### Source(s) of original content
>
> Please provide the location(s) (e.g., website URLs, ISBNs, page numbers, etc.) of the original content for us to investigate.

Comment: This will limit some form of automation if it were to be available in the future or if it is currently feasible in a limited scope (for example doing an internal search lookup when the url is within the stack exchange network; this would be efficient because it would not require scraping and could be done with existing hooks). While it is true that there are other sources of plagiarism, those should be addressed in a different field altogether.

Comment: Allowing you to type anything you want in the field, but heavily implying that the source should be something accessible on the Web was very much by design. These flags go to moderators, who manually verify the reports of plagiarism. How do you expect us to verify something when you give us an ISBN and page number (assuming we don't have that exact copy/edition of the book, which we almost certainly don't, even though I have a massive library of books)? Having it on the Web makes it immediately verifiable. If it's not on the web, you likely need to provide other evidence (e.g., photos).

Comment: @CodyGray One thing that this answer includes is plagiarism from ChatGPT or other AI sources, where there isn't exactly a URL one can provide - instead, it'd be "the output of [x] from generator [y]". Also, what are users supposed to do if something's plagiarized from a print source? Just not report it? With regards to such reports, most local libraries and universities provide access to databases where one can enter the ISBN and have access to the book to verify the plagiarism. These may not provide stable links, and the procedure to access them would be different for each institution.

Comment: @gparyani as ChrisF stated in the comments on the announcements, you should still be using a custom mod flag for ChatGPT content. Print sourced plagiarism should (___obviously___) still be reported, but if possible, try to link to an publicly accessible version of the printed source.

Comment: You can always take a picture of the printed source you're looking at, upload it to imgur (or wherever), and add the link to your flag.

Answer (score 20):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The "Why do you consider this answer to be plagiarized?" field is too small and cannot be resized. It can only display two <sup>(well, two and a half)</sup> lines at a time:

[image: 'Plagiarized content' flag]

I'm not sure if this was intentional because the screenshot in the question shows the same field having a much bigger height:

[image]

Please either increase the height of that field or (preferably) make it resizable.

Related feature request of mine: [Make the text field for mod flags resizable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385442/348196)

Answer (score 12):

To be abundantly clear: I'm asking that this be addressed in the written guidance/FAQs for flaggers, for moderators, and to which users flagged for plagiarism are directed.  It's not a hot path and doesn't need to be in the UI, but should be found in the linked additional information.

---

What protections exist to detect and prevent deletion of original content that may also exist elsewhere?

We all hope that plagiarism flags are raised while content is very new, making it impossible that the post on SO is upstream of the identical copy elsewhere.  (But see <sup>1</sup> below).

But realistically this won't always be the case.  And we know that many other sites plagiarize from Stack Overflow, both automated en-masse copying (which tends to still look like Q&A after being scraped), and focused manual copying by individuals, which may result in inclusion in blog posts, white papers, or even printed books.  And those copies may not be truthful about the date/time they appeared.

<sup>1</sup> Another possibility is that the author of the content used it both on and off of Stack Overflow, which is permissible.

---

There may be good reasons for not disclosing the web link to the other copy of the content, which is believed to be the upstream source, to the poster... but not doing so makes it more difficult for the author of the content to defuse mistaken plagiarism accusations.

What is the expected experience for an author who wrote the content and later has it wrongly deleted "for reasons of plagiarism" by a moderator?

Comment: While this is likely better answered by the mods, who are handling most of these flags, based on my experience of handling plagiarism-related CM escalations, I try to keep the following in mind: **First** I check the date of posting. Is the SO post newer or older? If it's older, it's not plagiarism on the SO end... otherwise, it likely is. **Second** I compare the username of the SO user with the author of the older content (where available). If they match or I have other reasons to think they may be the same person, it's not plagiarism... otherwise, I treat it as such.

Comment: While this isn't perfect (particularly in the latter case), these checks do exist on the mods' end of things - though they're not built in. Additionally, in cases where the user is the original author, a flag stating such and offering evidence of such would likely lead to a quick undeletion of the post. The new UX is actually an improvement, as in cases where we disassociated, it would require a CM to reassociate to get the rep back. Now, the mod need only undelete and the rep will return.

Comment: @Catija : I already mentioned it, but "Is the SO post newer or older?"  Newer or older than *what*?  The date/time claimed by the other copy?  Is any proof required that said date is accurate?

Comment: While I don't do it, generally the mods and even the people raising plagiarism flags will use web archive links to show that the non-SO content is older. Plus, much of the copied content is on SO, so the dates can't be fudged.

Comment: In any case, there should be some kind of written guidance about this both to those who cast plagiarism flags and to those authors who may be flagged wrongly.

Comment: For authors whose posts are flagged wrongly, they can simply raise a moderator intervention flag, as suggested in the post notice.  In practice, I don't think I've ever seen a plagiarism deletion reversed for a falsely backdated post, and maybe one or two (out of thousands) for being the actual author of the content.

Comment: For flaggers...I mean, I'd hope it's obvious that the source needs to predate the post. Additionally, the bulk of plagiarism flags are cast by a small group of people who are in close contact with moderators (and each other), so tips and assistance on verifying such things are easy to come by.

Comment: In general, I haven't really seen much, if any, in the way of falsely backdated posts when searching for sources.  It tends to be either 1) the date of the source material, or 2) falsely newer (presumably to appear "fresher" to searchers).  The SO scraping sites tend to be quite obvious, either being obvious copies of the source question and answers (sometimes run through machine translation) or long lists of semi-related content poorly strung together.

Comment: This seems to be asking about what SO is going to do to prevent nefarious activity occurring in the outside world. SO has never really set policy or created site features that were contingent upon any particular behavior in the outside world, and it is unreasonable to expect them to do so. If this is not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: @TylerH: No, it is not about stopping nefarious activity in the outside world, it is about preventing/mitigating/minimizing the susceptibility of moderation inside Stack Overflow to false outside information.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's already the expectation for any report to moderators: that it is based on truthful information.

Comment: @TylerH: That would be problematic if the moderators blindly trust the outside source.  (And that trust sets up the exact opposite of your previous comment "SO has never really set policy or created site features that were contingent upon any particular behavior in the outside world").  Even in the case where the flagger is honestly repeating (but not verifying) the information they found.

Comment: I don't think there's any "blind trust" going on... heck, even the CMs when we get these escalations don't take the mods on faith. I investigate every single one I get as if no one else has looked at it and if I'm confused about why the mod's requesting it, I have the space to ask for more details or just push back... people can definitely make mistakes but that's why the system is designed to be easy to fix when mistakes happen.

Comment: @Catija: Gentle reminder that the two-way conversation that exists between mod and CM doesn't exist earlier in the process.  Which is why the written guidance should raise the point.

Comment: There is a two-way conversation between the mods and the person whose posts are deleted, though - mods send them a mod message, which the user can respond to. Your answer here seems to be concerned that content may be deleted incorrectly and I feel like both the mods and I have explained that the onus is on the mod to confirm the SO post is newer when deleting it. Even if we told flaggers in help documents to look out for this, what would doing so change? Mods would still have to review and confirm.

Comment: @Catija: Flaggers would be more likely to put archive.org links in flags (or wikipedia history links) instead of direct links.  And some wrong accusations might be figured out before flagging and never reach the mods.  Both these outcomes save moderator time, and the latter results in fewer declined flags and fewer frustrated flaggers.  What fraction of Stack Overflow users do you think are actually aware that authors retain copyright to their posts on SO and are free to copy them elsewhere?

Comment: Re *"And those copies may not be truthful about the date/time they appeared."*: Yes, that is a risk. E.g., it is easy to do in [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress). But it still requires effort. Most plagiarisers are ***much*** more concerned with minimum effort rather than detection of their misdeeds. There is also very little obfuscation going on. Most is wholesale copying (requires minimum effort).

Comment: @Catija: *"think they may be the same person, it's not plagiarism"*: Often the plagiarism has taken place on another site. E.g., they have wholesale copied some older blog post to their [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)) account. [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-can-i-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-os-x-v10-10-yo/66221264#66221264) (of plagiarism taking place on another site, not copied to Stack Overflow).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: And of course plagiarism between two external sites, prior to an SO post, confuses the authorship test and can result in either false negatives or false positives, depending on whether the SO post was made by the content owner or the serial plagiarist.

Answer (score 8):

> To request undeletion, edit your post to [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) all content written by others and then flag the post "in need of moderation intervention."

What's the likelihood of a plagiarized post actually being salvaged by edits? I imagine the chances are almost nil, so this wording seems like it would just give false hope to OPs and extra burden to mods.

Should the wording be modified to dampen expectation/entitlement? Maybe something that references [causes for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) or [elements of a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), e.g.:

> To request undeletion, edit your post to [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) all content written by others **and** remove all other [causes for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Then flag the post "in need of moderation intervention."

I'm not married to this new wording and welcome suggestions. My main point is just to highlight that the deployed wording invites plagiarizers to think they can get their copy-pasted answer undeleted by just tacking on a citation.

Comment: The focus of the post notice is on the reason the post was deleted - plagiarism. Removing all links to resources about how to fix plagiarism seems like it would leave the user very confused and even less likely to improve the post. While I understand what you're getting at, I feel like it's best to focus on one problem at a time. The mods are well-equipped to respond to requests for undeletion to explain any blockers if they still exist.

Comment: @Catija If you're referring to missing "reference" hyperlink, that was just because I transcribed the message from an image. I wasn't suggesting to remove the "reference" hyperlink, only to add extra context. I've hyperlinked it now to avoid confusion.

Comment: I feel the ordering of the "To request undeletion, …" variant is better than the "If you edit your post …" variant since it a) directly gets authors at what *they* want and b) makes it clearer that editing/revision is a *prerequisite* for undeletion.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not tied to my particular wording. I was just trying to highlight that the current wording invites users to think, "Oh so if I just add a citation to my copy-pasted answer, they'll undelete it." Maybe I shouldn't have provided a wording sample (or I should propose multiple samples) because it seems comments are now about my specific sample instead of the overall idea.

Comment: I do not see in how a post that is completely plagiarized from another post can be salvaged. Just adding a reference to the original writer doesn't help there, as [answers that are completely from another source are also not allowed, even with reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Yeah, so I do understand your point (and apologies if I focused too much on your specific variation). I think we're going to leave it as is for now but, since we'll be keeping an eye on this, we can certainly also watch the flags on these posts from the OP to determine whether the message is causing confusion and mods are frequently declining requests to undelete due to the post having other issues than merely the unsourced content. :)

Comment: " I imagine the chances are almost nil" <- Why is not almost 100%? A link to the source makes it not-plagiarism, doesn't it?

Comment: @tdy: If users think that, are they not correct? There is no requirement of originality in SO posts, is there?

Comment: @einpoklum [/help/referencing](/help/referencing) says (bold added): "Do _not_ copy the complete text of sources ... answers comprised entirely of a quote **(sourced or not)** will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content." Anecdotally, the plagiarized posts I've seen are just copy-pastes, but of course I can't speak definitively of the full scope.

Comment: And actually I think this highlights another key distinction. A copy-paste answer with citation will no longer be "plagiarism" by definition, but it will still be delete-worthy by SO standards (which is not evident from the post notice wording -- they have to actually read the [/help/referencing](/help/referencing) link in detail). That's another reason why this could cause confusion and friction.

Comment: @tdy: About your second-last comment: This post said nothing about "complete texts". Nor are SO answers typically complete articles. So, if I write an unattributed SO answer, I won't be breaking that rule you mentione anyway; the only problem would be attribution. Now, if you're saying that snippets of content break this rule, then I'm afraid you have to remove... maybe 5-10% of all of SO answers.

Comment: @einpoklum In OP's first link ([We need a dedicated plagiarism flag](/q/381806)), Machavity specifically mentioned how lots of users just "copy the best answer(s)." That's what I was referring to -- users just copy-pasting the "complete text" of other SO answers -- which I see all the time.

Comment: I believe that's also what @The_spider was alluding to above.

Comment: @tdy: But aren't those just cases of duplicate questions?

Comment: @einpoklum My experience is in [LQA](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) / [LA](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) / [FA](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) / [NAOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) where I see users copy-pasting the top/accepted answer in part or whole (_literally from the same Q_) as their "new" answer. That's where my perspective comes from. You/others might be encountering other types of plagiarism regularly that I'm not seeing (probably why it's hard to build unified tooling for the entire community).