# What should I do about an answer that is majority copy/paste of another answer?

Tags: discussion

- First: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66637144
- Second: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73031568

Please note the first one has a datetime that is about 1 year earlier. So the second is more likely a copy of the first.

Also the second answer does not quote or properly.

##### What should I do about an answer that is majority copy/paste of another answer? Flag the answer?

I am not sure.

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73031568) is clearly plagiarism and should be flagged as such.

Comment: What to do -> [Plagiarism flag and moderator tooling has launched to Stack Overflow!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749)

Comment: i flagged with the "plagarism". FYI.

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and flagged the second answer for plagiarism, and I recommend everybody else do the same

Comment: @Fastnlight I'm not sure the moderators need dozens of plagiarism flags on a single answer, I'm sure one is enough.

Comment: I'll go raise another

Comment: (side note: i do hope that the flagging is somehow "nice". the old "duplicate" question flag used to be "mean" but the new one is "nice" because it says "hey does this other question answer your question?".

Comment: The moderators are given new pairs of the softest velvet gloves scented with the smell of spring flowers. They don these before slapping the user for plagiarism.

Comment: @VLAZ i looked after marking and there is no public facing indication of "plagarism". so it looks like "sweeping it under the rug" a little bit.

Comment: There is no public facing action because, in general, the moderation style is to avoid just shaming and labelling people publicly. Putting some sort of marker for "plagiarised" would fall under that. Instead offending content is deleted or potentially edited to comply, if it has merit (and can be edited to comply). The user would also be sent a private message. Mod response to plagiarism flags is to also investigate other posts by the account s often users who post plagiarism do it repeatedly.